# Datatables and dropdown select in row jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm using datatables.net's script and have a dropdown select in one row there I can select a status.

I'm using this code:

```
<script>
$(function () {

    $('#select-first').on('change', function () {

        var options = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        var ids = "<?php echo $ord['order_id']; ?>";
        var selecto = 'id=' + ids + '&option=' + options;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update_status.php",
            data: selecto,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                alert("yes");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
<select id="select-first" name="status" class="ui compact dropdown">
    <option value="1">Behandlas</option>
    <option value="2">Bearbetas</option>
    <option value="3">Nekades</option>
    <option value="4">Klar</option>
    <option value="5">Klar/Betald</option>
</select>
```

It won't work when I chose page 2 in datatables script.

Comment: please, provide us a jsfidlle to play with

Comment: There you go. http://jsfiddle.net/h2m1vg29/

Test on page 2 if it says "hej"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Datable load, it removes the extra HTML that is not currently displayed.
So if you want to attach event you have multiple options :

**1. Attach the events before you call the function datatable**

```
    $('.select-first').on('change', function(e) {

    alert("hej");
    var options = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    var ids = "<?php echo $ord['order_id']; ?>";
    var selecto = 'id='+ ids + '&option='+ options;
});
$('#myTable').DataTable();
```

**2. use the delegate function :**

```
$('#myTable').DataTable();

$('#myTable').delegate('.select-first', 'change', function () {


    alert("hej");
    var options = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    var ids = "<?php echo $ord['order_id']; ?>";
    var selecto = 'id='+ ids + '&option='+ options;
});
```

**3. use the fnDrawCallback**

```
$('#myTable').DataTable({"fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
     $('.select-first').on('change', function(e) {

    alert("hej");
    var options = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    var ids = "<?php echo $ord['order_id']; ?>";
    var selecto = 'id='+ ids + '&option='+ options;
});
}});
```

That should be enough way to put it

1. http://jsfiddle.net/h2m1vg29/3/
2. http://jsfiddle.net/h2m1vg29/2/
3. http://jsfiddle.net/h2m1vg29/1/

Comment: Thank you! Made me understand much :)